# casting a returned iterator to const

Tags: c++, type-conversion, const-iterator

I have the following `for` statement in my code:

```
for (auto Iter = Target.begin(), 
        IterEnd = std::stable_partition(Target.begin(), Target.end(), Check);
    Iter != IterEnd; ++Iter)
    { /* loop statement */ }
```

The point is that the loop doesn't modify elements of the container, so it would make sense to declare iterators as `const_iterator`. I can easily solve the problem for the first using `cbegin()`, but the second is more complex. I can't declare `cbegin()` and `cend()` inside `stable_partition`, since of course `stable_partition` needs `non const_iterators` to do its work.

A possible solution is to replace auto with the proper type, which in this case was `std::vector< std::string >::const_iterator`. This forces the conversion from `iterator` to `const_iterator` on the second assignment.

Though, I don't like it. Types can easily and rapidly become unmanageable, so I'm looking for a solution that lets me use auto, without the need to declare something weird outside the loop. Any suggestion?

Comment: I am not sure about your idea of type unmanageability. Being explicit in your type declaration, if that solves your problem, is a fine approach. `auto` is convenient, but I wouldn’t say it is necessarily more manageable than being clear on the types you are using.

Comment: I would definitely move all this stuff out of loop prologue. `auto Iter{Target.cbegin()}; decltype(Target)::const_iterator const IterEnd{std::stable_partition(Target.begin(), Target.end(), Check)};`

Comment: you can use `decltype(Target.cbegin()) IterEnd`

Comment: Careful with your terminology: making the iterator const _doesn't_ make sense as you'll be incrementing it. ;)

Comment: Also note that `stable_partition` reorders the elements of `Target` (and possibly the first), so `Iter` might not point to the first element (depends on the container used). Invoke `stable_partition` first before you initialize `Iter`.

Answer (score 2):

The most clear solution in my opinion is to pull `std::stable_partition` before the `for`. This will result in an equivalent algorithm.

The problem is that `stable_partition` returns a iterator that can modify elements. Fortunately there is an implicit conversion from `container::iterator` to `container::const_iterator` (for most standard containers). To make the conversion you can specify the type of `IterEnd` with `std::vector<T::const_iterator`, or `decltyp(Target.cbegin()` or my personal preference:

```
auto Iter = Target.cbegin();
decltype(Iter) IterEnd = std::stable_partition(Target.begin(), Target.end(), Check);

for (; Iter != IterEnd; ++Iter)
{
}
```

For completeness you could keep all inside the `for` if you wish but it's less readable in my opinion:

```
for (auto Iter = Target.cbegin(),
        IterEnd = (decltype(Iter)) std::stable_partition(Target.begin(), Target.end(), Check);
     Iter != IterEnd;
     ++Iter)
{}
```

Comment: The call to `std::stable_partition` is in the preamble, so while philosophically we may claim it's "during the loop", it's not really, and thus your solution is not only good but also equivalent to the request. +1 but consider de-wrongising that opening para

Comment: You still say that the OP "needs" to pull `std::stable_partition` before the `for`, which is not true, though it does look much better this way (and I'm not sure the OP can get exactly what they want without it due to the single declaration statement in the preamble mixed with `for` - perhaps that's what you meant acutally?)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit hm... he could by using a cast

Comment: Indeed but I believe the point of the question is "cast to what? (without writing everything out rigidly)" - your answer does solve that perfectly by splitting the declaration into two, allowing us to use auto/decltype at both stages.

Comment: Does `auto x = f(), y = (decltype(x))g()` work I wonder (bet not)

Comment: Well, holy hannah!

Comment: (Answer's perfect now IMO)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to express the idea through a functional interface:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

namespace detail {
    template<class Container, class F>
    struct const_partitioned_target
    {
        using container_type = std::decay_t<Container>;
        using const_iterator = typename container_type::const_iterator;

        const_partitioned_target(Container& cont, F f)
            : first(cont.cbegin())
            , last(std::partition(cont.begin(), cont.end(), f))
        {

        }

        const_iterator begin() const { return first; }

        const_iterator end() const { return last; }

        const_iterator first, last;
    };
}

template<class Container, class F>
auto const_partitioned_target(Container& cont, F&& f)
{
    return detail::const_partitioned_target<Container, std::decay_t<F>>(cont, std::forward<F>(f));
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> Target { 1, 2, 6, 9, 10, 20, 30, 40 };

    auto Check = [](auto&& x)
    {
        return x < 10;
    };

    for(auto&& elem : const_partitioned_target(Target, Check))
    {
        // elem will have the type: int const&
        std::cout << elem << '\n';
    }
}
```

expected output:

```
1
2
6
9
```